# Bootstrap выравнивание по вертикали блоков

Tags: html5, bootstrap

Суть в следующем: надо выравнять блоки по вертикали, но примеры с оф. сайта почему-то не работает. Похожий вопрос уже был, но я не понял как он это пофиксил

```html
<div class = "container">
  <div class="row align-items-center">
   <div class="col" style='border:1px solid black'>1</div>
   <div class="col" style='border:1px solid black'>2</div> 
   <div class="col" style='border:1px solid black'>3</div> 
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Почему вы решили, что не работает? Если родительскому элементу колонок (`.row`) не задана определенная высота или колонки имеют одинаковую высоту, то эффект вы не увидите.

```css
.row {
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid #060;
}

.col {
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row align-items-center">
    <div class="col">1</div>
    <div class="col">2</div>
    <div class="col">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.row {
  border: 1px solid #060;
}

.col {
  border: 1px solid #999;
}

.col:nth-child(2) {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row align-items-center">
    <div class="col">1</div>
    <div class="col">2</div>
    <div class="col">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, теперь я понял в чем проблема.